# Fuelphp ORM where in

Tags: orm, model, fuelphp, where-in

I have this database logic that need to be executed, I want to get all the rows selected by the user and deleted it.

My database logic would be getting all the rows and then delete individually.

I'm using Fuelphp 1.6 so my code is(as per stated on [fuelphp forum topic in ORM](http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/9787/proper-way-to-generate-a-where-in-query#Item_6)):

```
Model_Article::find()->where('id', 'IN', array(1,3))->get();
```

The problem is I got this error:

```
Call to a member function where() on a non-object
```

Note: Model_Article extends ORM\Model

Can anybody help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: find() without parameters was deprecated in v1.4, and removed in v1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right... change your "select" to this:

```
Model_Article::find('all', array('where' => array('id', 'IN', array(1,3))))
```

OR change your select to

```
Model_Article::query()->where('id', 'IN', array(1,3))->get();
```

After you can do a "delete" in every record.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality to chain methods using Model::find()->foo().. was deprecated in 1.4 and removed in 1.5.

https://github.com/fuel/fuel/blob/1.6/master/CHANGELOG.md#removed-code-because-it-was-deprecated-in-v14-or-earlier